# How to navigate through code while having the QuickView window open?

Tags: debugging, exception, visual-studio-2019

When something throws an exception I usually click on "View details" which brings the `QuickWatch` window into the foreground and let's me examine the occurred exception.

What really bugs me is that I am not able to browse/search through my code having the `QuickWatch` window open next to it. I first have to close the window.

Is there a way to keep the window open when in break? Maybe there is another approach?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep the window open when in break? Maybe there is
>   another approach?

Actually, there is no such function to browse or search the source code when you call **Quick Watch** window. And when you call the **Quick Window**, it will lock the current interface and we cannot do any other operation on other window. And this is  the **Quick Window** feature in Debug mode.

> Is there a way to keep the window open when in break? Maybe there is
>   another approach?

**In fact**, there is no such function to achieve your goal. Detecting exceptions is the job of the Debug mode process. If Debug mode is broken, the exception cannot be monitored, so it cannot be implemented. It must be based on Debug mode to capture.

**As a suggestion**, you can try this:

**Suggestion**

**1)** When you achieve the Error `Exception User Unhandled` under Debug mode, you can first browse/search through your code in Code Editor.

**2)** After that, you can keep the current interface of your code section, open Quick Watch Window(`Debug`-->`QuickWatch`)-->input `$exception` in the **Expression** textbox and click **Reevaluate**.

[image]

And this will be the same as shown earlier.